# Is there an implementation of Levenshtein distance or similar for iphone?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to take a string entered in an iphone app and populate a tableview with strings from a dictionary that are likely correct spellings of the word.  I understand levenshtein distance is the way to do this but wondering if anyone was aware of any way to do this natively or whether there was a library that i could use?

Comment: There is this thing called Google: http://www.merriampark.com/ldobjc.htm

Comment: @Dawson I thought people understood how timestamps work?
 https://web.archive.org/web/20110929114224/merriampark.com/ldobjc.htm

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the implementation referenced in the comments, there is also a implementation [here](https://gist.github.com/1515464) which gives you a bit more flexibility and is built for 64bit.